# Uniform convergence on compact set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ a compact support function on the open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and let $x\in\Omega$ a fixed point ($f\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$). How can I see that the sequence $f(\varepsilon z + x)$ converges uniformly to the function $f(x)$ for $\varepsilon \to 0$ respect to $z\in \partial \mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B}$ is the unite ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$? Is there a criterion should I use?
Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: The key is that $f$ is uniformly continuous (because it has compact support): this implies that convergence is uniform (not only pointwise).

Comment: @Crostul thank you very much!